Identify Regulator from Canon Camera CMOS Board
I'm trying to Identify 3 Regulators from a Canon Camera CMOS Board
The only hint I have is L814, A1BE5, LA42
But I don't know how to find the actual reference of the parts, I need them to repair my camera. I added a picture with the specific regulators im looking to find.
Thanks

